# CTB-LOCKER and possible future decrypt hack. Do I make a HD ISO image before formatting?

Tags: security, virus, iso-image

my second question here! :)

A friend of mine has the files on his laptop (Windows based OS) hard-disk encrypted by the ransomware CTB-LOCKER.
I don't know the CTB-LOCKER ransomware version/type, anyway I know that is impossible to decrypt the files without paying the ransom **nowdays**.

He will format and reinstall OS to clean the laptop well (just the laptop needed).

I was thinking if it would be intelligent to make an ISO HD image of the infected HD before formatting.
**Is it possible that in the next months someone discover an hack to decrypt files without paying the ransom?!** Or there is no hope?!
**Having the HD ISO image available he could mount that ISO and work on that by the "future" hack if available**!

He will not pay the ransom but as you can understand he has a lot of important job datas there and he has not a backup... fool..

I have also a personal curiosity: is it possible for CTB-LOCKER to attack and install itself in a system if you use the PC logging in by a guest/powerguest user account?!

What about Linux?! I use Linux Mint but I am a newbie... is it under attack, too?!

Thank you very much! :)

Comment: The chances of the malware authors still having the private key in 6-12+ months is very unlikely.  **is it possible for CTB-LOCKER to attack and install itself in a system if you use the PC logging in by a guest/powerguest user account?!** -  Yep

Comment: Hello Ramhound, thank you but I explained bad... I don't hope they give me the key for free in a year! :D I hope someone find an hack to crack the LOCKER encrypting.

Comment: Its unlikely.  An analysis of CTB Locker was done, it was clearly written by people, who knew what they were doing.  There has to be an exploit that exists, even if there is, the private key still has to exist in order to decrypt the files.

Answer (score 0):

I agree there may be value in backing up because the way this works - and indeed it may even be possie to recover some s
data from it (due to the way it encrypts - recoverable deleted copies of some data probably exist, and might be recoverable with photorec or similar).

In order to fo the best possible backup you really eant to do a bitcopy of the drive. Linux has powerful tools to do this - my favourite being ”gnu ddrescue”, but even dd or pv commands can do it. It is possible to use these to make an image file of the drive- and pv and dd can even be piped to gzip or similar to compress it (but that will make it slower to use to recover data later on as it will need to be decrypted first.)

Clonezilla and Parted Magic apparently offer GUI cloning options, and there are probably windows options as well (but using Linux is safer).